# Can I send an extra parameter (unique character) while performing the device firmware upgrade using react native nordic dfu library?

Tags: react-native, nrf52, nrf51, dfu

I'm wondering if we can send a unique character during the startDFU() method, so that the device can validate this character first and then initiate the firmware upgrade.
Is this possible with this library (React native nordic dfu)?

Comment: Why do you want to send this extra character? To allow only specific devices to perform a DFU?

Comment: @M.Kotzjan Yes, to allow only those devices that have the character to perform DFU.

Comment: You could manually send a character to a characteristic of your choice using a normal BLE library before attempting the DFU.  Is "React native nordic dfu" resetting you device into bootloader or are you manually doing it before the DFU?

Comment: I think, RN nordic dfu is doing it,

Comment: Why do you need to do this extra authentication? Is using the secure DFU procedure with a signed DFU package not enough for you? You can prevent the usage of an unofficial dfu package and even a downgrade using an older package